# How to set minimum window size in Compact overlay mode of UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, picture-in-picture

There is a button in my UWP app which enters app into picture-in-picture mode. The window size in PIP mopde can be changed between 150 x 150 and 500 x 500 and also I can set the window size while entering into compact overlay mode. But I want to limit the minimum window size of app in PIP mode. How can I restrict the app resizing to default 150x150 min size.

```
 var applicationView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
 var viewModePreference = ViewModePreferences.CreateDefault(ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay);
 viewModePreference.CustomSize = new Size(width, height);

 applicationView.SetPreferredMinSize(new Size(360, 400));
 await applicationView.TryEnterViewModeAsync(ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay, viewModePreference);
```

SetPreferredMinSize() is not solving the purpose. Please help me with the solution. Thankyou

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.viewmodepreferences.customsize?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ViewModePreferences_CustomSize

Comment: https://programmer.group/uwp-use-compact-overlay-mode-to-always-display-on-the-front-end.html

Answer (score 1):

Please check [`SetPreferredMinSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.setpreferredminsize#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ApplicationView_SetPreferredMinSize_Windows_Foundation_Size_) documentation,

> The smallest allowed minimum size is 192 x 48 effective pixels. The largest allowed minimum size is 500 x 500 effective pixels. If you set a value outside of these bounds, it is coerced to be within the allowed bounds. (To learn about effective pixels, see Responsive design 101 for .)

So, please edit your largest width 150 to 192.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   
    var size = new Size(192,150);
    ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(size);
}
```

**Update**

if you want to limit the users to resize the window in overlay mode. please listen `SizeChanged` event and resize pip view when user change the window size.

```
private  void CoreWindow_SizeChanged(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var applicationView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
    if(applicationView.ViewMode == ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay)
    {

        var size = new Size(200, 200);                        
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gone through the documentation earlier, as per that anything between 192x48 and 500x500 is acceptable. And the same "SetPreferredMinSize(new size(360, 400))" is used on Onlaunched event of app which is limiting the app to resize further. I want to acheive the same for Compact Overlay mode